# Expansion Panel with Text Field input change the panel's back color on input focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

When creating an expansion panel with text field inside the 'ExpansionPanelSummary', the expansion panel background color always change to #E0E0E0 (grey[500]) when focusing the text field input.

Focusing the text field change the expansion panel background color to grey[500] without the ability to override the color (I tried every way I know).
It's also happens on 'dark' theme which makes the text field to be 'invisible' when typing

CodeSandbox demonstrate the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/expansionpanelissue-ysizh

Will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `!important`

```
  expansionPanel: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue !important",
```

solved the problem of how to keep the `expansion panel background color` when focusing on the child `<TextField />`.

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]